# Best practice to find out something about state in Vuex (function that doesn't commit a mutation)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I didn't find anything close to my question so I decided to ask it here.

In Vuex we have actions, mutations, getters and store itself. What if we have a need to make a function that checks if something in store meets a certain condition or we would like to find out something specific about data in our state without commiting a mutation?

Let's consider an example. We have a variable called "house" in our store. It can have multiple floors and on some floors there can be duplex apartments. We would like to know, how many duplex apartments are there in the house. So the function should have access to state and should return the number of such apartments. If we need to use this function in different components, we need to have it somewhere within the global scope.

Another example to make it clear. We have the same variable "house" and we need to know, if the house is a skyscraper (has more than 100 floors, for example) or not. So this function is a predicate that returns a boolean value.

The question is: should we use getters or something else, for example, some kind of global helpers for this purpose? What are best practices for such cases and why? Please, give and explanation in your answer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `getters`

Comment: @TheReason can you give an explanation of your answer and make it a separate answer so I can mark it afterwards, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the exact role of `getter`s. Getters are a part of Vuex store and they are used to calculate data based on store state, it's some kind of *computed* properties for stores.

Here are couple examples of state & getters

```
state: {
  houses: [
    {id: 0, floors: 10},
    {id: 1, floors: 20},
    {id: 2, floors: 100}
    {id: 3, floors: 400}
  ]
},

getters: {

  // you can have dummy one
  getHouses(state){
    return state.houses
  },

  // or you can get a specific one like so
  getHouseFilteredBySpecificFloor(state){
    return floors => state.houses.filter(house => house.floors === floors)
  },

  // or you can return boolean if you want
  doesThisHouseHaveMoreThan100Floor(state){
    return ({ id }) => state.houses[id].floors > 100
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and examples!